# Xamarin - IO operations fail when using PCLStorage mirrors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard

so I'm trying to access the file system on a Xamarin Forms project, I used several projects including:

[StandardStorage](https://github.com/RefactorForce/StandardStorage)

[StorageEverywhere](https://github.com/yunusefendi52/StorageEverywhere)

[XamFileStorageNetStandard](https://github.com/DuckArne/XamStorage.Library)

All are Net Standard mirrors of PCL Storage, no code change is required.

I can grab the current file system from my Forms project and grab the root folder of the local storage, response is something like:

```
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.APPNAME/files"
```

When I try to perform any operation on this path, E.G:

```
await FileUtility.RootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("test", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
await FileUtility.RootFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
await FileUtility.RootFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

All operations just block and never return, tested on a OnePlus 6T.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Clarify that the libraries were referenced also on the platform specific projects as required.

Comment: Did you apply the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure I have to, since it is not external storage, it's my local application folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will have problems in the future, simply use System.IO for handling files, apparently it works.

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

Use it for accessing your app's local storage.